# use the internet connection of a remote desktop

Tags: internet, remote-desktop

I'm a web developer and not a hardware/software type of a man. I have something in mind but I don't know if possible. So here goes nothing.

I have internet connection at home and I can connect to my desktop at work via **Remote Desktop Connection**.

Internet at work is faster than mine at home. So my question is if it's possible to use the internet at my work place using my remote desktop access? I mean use it in my desktop at home and not at `the desktop at work viewed by the remote desktop` window.

Please enlighten me. Thanks.

note: what I have is the IP and the administrator account of that remote PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your slow network at home is the limiting factor making any connection from home slow. The fact that you can control your work machine doesn't magically make your home Internet connection any faster.

Let's say your home network is crappy 128kbps IDSL, and your work is connected to the Internet via ~45mbps DS3. Your work machine could download a file at 45mbps, but to get that file from work to home, it still has to come over your 128kbps IDSL.

If the problem was that your home network connection is filtered and doesn't let you get to the same sites you can get to from work, then that's a different story. Setting up a proxy or tunnel of some sort would be useful. But if it's just about getting more bandwidth at home, no amount of tunneling or proxying is going to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

*Your internet connection is only ever going to be as fast as the slowest part of it*, so you would still be limited by your connection between home and work.

However, you could look into setting up a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN) between home and work, where you could potentially use your work connection for large downloads (like BitTorrent).  You could transfer the files to your home computer when they have finished downloading.  I cannot think if any other way that you could utilise your work internet connection at home.

Answer (score 1):

YES.  If your aim is do work from home as if you are using the computer at work and it's internet connection at work, then yes.

If you understand that you are using the connection between your home computer and the work computer STRICTLY as a VERY LONG VIDEO CABLE, then you can take advantage of your work's T1 connection (should you be so blessed) for work that requires a T1 connection.

For example, you are at work finishing some sort of massive project that requires alot of bandwidth (or even processing power) that you do not have at home.  It's 5pm and it will be another 3 hours of work before it is completed.  The work computer is compiling the information and simultaneously uploading it at T1 speeds.  Even with T1 Speeds and your computer's crunching power, both the computer and you are more efficient if only one of you are working.

So you go home early, and let the computer crunch and upload.  You make dinner at home, eat, and at 7pm get back to work finishing off/monitoring the rest of the process.

With the remote desktop configuration, you could work at T1 speeds, seeing the results via video.

However, if you want a magical T1 connection to your home computer you are out of luck.

Comment: However, even if the work computer can download the data at much faster speeds, sending an entire screen of data back to your own computer at home with the bandwidth of a "very long video cable" would require, likely, an even faster connection than the work computer would have. So, some amount of video compression and slow screen update speeds will be occurring. So say if you were using your work computer to watch a Netflix movie, while if you were sitting at work it would be smooth, at home you'd see a slideshow, because you can't update the picture fast enough over the slow home connection.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot have the same performance that you achieve in your office desktop.
Your internet speed at home and at work is limiting this.